# Laravel mix - change output dir of numbered js files

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using laravel mix together with vuejs.

In my `webpack.mix.js` I am setting the paths for sass and js compilation:

```
mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

when I run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` it works as expected.

But because of vuejs, I get a couple of additional js files (`1.js`, `2.js`, etc.), which are stored directly under `public`. Is there a way, that these files are generated under `public/js`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the output location of these files by adding this to your mix config file

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  output: {
    chunkFilename: "js/[name].js",
  }
});
```

If you want to add a hash to the filename for caching purposes, you can adjust `chunkFilename` like so:

`chunkFilename: "js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js"`